# How to open array from file return ['field1','field2']

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a settings.php file witch contains

```
<?php
return [
    'setting1' => 'value1',
    'setting2' => 'value2',
    'setting3' => 'value3',
];
```

My question is : How can i read/use this array
in my index.php file?

Got 2 files :
index.htm
settings.php

Didn't find any information about this.
Only arrays like $field = array('','',''). That way i know how..

Comment: Where you want to use this array, in same file, or upload to another?

Comment: jspit gives me the answer already :) sorry i didn't explain it more clearly from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

settings.php

```
<?php
return [
    'setting1' => 'value1',
    'setting2' => 'value2',
    'setting3' => 'value3',
];
```

Our Test.php

```
<?php
//settings.php is in the same directory
$field = require 'settings.php';

var_export($field);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'setting1' => 'value1',
  'setting2' => 'value2',
  'setting3' => 'value3',
)
```

**Note from PHP Manual:**

It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function. This is not, however, possible when including remote files unless the output of the remote file has valid PHP start and end tags (as with any local file). You can declare the needed variables within those tags and they will be introduced at whichever point the file was included.

Comment: super thanks! 
Didn't saw that in the manual. And i have searched on a few places for the answer.